# Calculate the length of curve $f(x)=\arcsin(e^x)$, check solution, please.

Tags: integration, summation

As in the topic, my task is to calculate the length of $f(x)=\arcsin(e^x)$ between $-1, 0$. My solution: I use the the fact, that the length of $f(x)$ is equal to $\int_{a}^b\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx$ $$f'(x)=(\arcsin(e^x))'=\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^x}}\rightarrow (f'(x))^2=\frac{e^{2x}}{1-e^x}$$Next I use binomial coefficient:$$ \left (1+ \frac{e^{2x}}{1-e^x}\right )^\frac{1}{2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}\frac{e^{2xn}}{(1-e^x)^n}$$Let's evaluate $\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}=\frac{1}{n!}\cdot(\frac{1}{2})(-\frac{1}{2})(-\frac{3}{2})\cdot\dots\cdot(\frac{-2n+3}{2})=\dots=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)(n!)^2}\cdot\binom{2n}{n}$Hence the length is $$\int_{-1}^0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)(n!)^2}\cdot\binom{2n}{n}\cdot \frac{e^{2xn}}{(1-e^x)^n}dx$$Normally I would integrate it but it is nasty and I am not sure whether it is correct. Any hints, ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're wrong at the very first step. What is the derivative of $\arcsin(x)$?

Comment: Unfortunately, there was an early differentiation error, the derivative should be $\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}$. That will make life much easier.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$...

Comment: However the integral is still nasty, is this correct way to do it?

Comment: And the result will be in terms of summation, doesn't it?

Comment: @fdhd No, a summation is not necessary. I've added more steps to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derivative is slightly off, because you've neglected the squaring in the denominator of $\arcsin$'s derivative. The integral winds up as $$\int_{-1}^0\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-e^{2x}}}\,dx$$ which actually has an elementary antiderivative, so there will be no need for an infinite series. Substituting $$e^{x}=\sin(u)$$ gives

$$\int_{\arcsin(e^{-1})}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-\sin^2(u)}}\,\frac{\cos(u)\,du}{\sin(u)}$$

or just $$\int_{\arcsin(e^{-1})}^{\pi/2}\csc(u)\,du$$

Answer (score 2):

I think your initial derivative is off, so:

$$f'(x)=\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-e^{2x}}}$$

Then:

$$(f'(x))^2 = \frac{e^{2x}}{1-e^{2x}}$$

So we have:

$$\int_{-1}^0 \sqrt{1+\frac{e^{2x}}{1-e^{2x}}} = \int_{-1}^0 \sqrt{\frac{1}{1-e^{2x}}}$$

Then the rest might make more sense.